# Partition Issue (Using unallocated space)- GParted

Tags: dual-boot, disk-management

So I previously used dual-boot and had windows and linux running but decided to switch to only Linux (elementary OS). The unallocated space was from deleting the partition for my windows. I am now having trouble to resize my */dev/sda5* partition. I am trying to completely allocate the 88.51GB to my */dev/sda5* partition.

[image: Image of Partition]
[image: Attempt to resize Partition]

Comment: @Jeroen is correct, you cannot resize your mounted root partition while using it, you need to load up a live USB or CD in order to achieve this. You can get more advice here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/60431/how-do-i-resize-root-partition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the partition you're currently using.

Try resizing the partition using a live USB.